# Xamarin Studio HtmlHelper Missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, xamarin, html-helper, xamarin-studio

For some reason my `HtmlHelper` won't load in my `Razor` view.

If you type `@Html.` , a popup box should pop up with a bunch of `Html` controls. I.E. `ActionLink`

But It does not. Does anyone know why?

Main `Web.conf`

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>

 <pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </controls>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="System.Linq" />
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Views `Web.conf`

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Razor"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I have tried just about everything and this is starting to annoy me now. It's like intellisense is completely broker for `Xamarin Studio`

**UPDATE:** If you open the same project in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed over to VS 2013. Think this was a Bug with Xamarin Studio, I'm hoping it will get resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@HtmlHelper.GenerateLink` instead of `@Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Not even `@HtmlHelper` comes up.